# IE9 placeholder attribute Modernizr and jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, internet-explorer-9, placeholder, modernizr

I have a mobile site that uses the jQuery Mobile library along with html5.  On this site I have made use of placeholders to label inputs (as I have hidden the labels).

However we all know that IE are inept and didn't support placeholders until IE10 but my client wants this to also work in IE9 (why he would want support for this on a mobile site is beyond me).

I have downloaded and installed the latest version of the [modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) script yet the placeholders still don't show up.  Is there anything I need to do to make this work?

My included scripts:

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>
```

Example html input

```
<input class="textbox" data-val="true" data-val-length="The field Surname * must be a string with a maximum length of 150." data-val-length-max="150" data-val-required="Please enter your surname." id="Surname" name="Surname" placeholder="Surame *" type="text" value="" />
```

[Example Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sym66/)

Comment: Why he'd want it on a mobile site? Older WinPhones have IE9 as their browser.

Comment: @Spudley surely that is a windows mobile version of IE9 rather than the desktop version and surely the market share for that isn't very large - I know one person out of probably all the people I know that has a windows phone and he doesn't use IE9 either

Comment: I agree, there's probably not a huge number of IE9 mobile devices, but they do exist. It's up to your client whether he wants to support them. If you think your client is wrong, feel free to argue the case with him. Or you could just do what he's asking for. (just be glad he's not asking for IE7-mobile or IE6-mobile)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Modernizr does not add the placeholders or any other functionality to old browsers.

Modernizr is simply a script that allows you to tell whether a browser supports any given feature or not. You still need to act on the information that Modernizr gives you, and implement the placeholder functionality if Modernizr tells you that it isn't supported.

Modernizr even provide a wiki page that lists a load of Polyfill scripts you can use for various features: https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills

Pick one of the placeholder scripts from that page, and do something like this:

```
Modernizr.load({
  test: Modernizr.input.placeholder,
  nope: 'placeholder-polyfill.js'
});
```

Comment: for some reason my console is saying Modernizr doesn't contain a method for load

Comment: not sure why you'd get that; it's correct as a far as I can see. But double-check in the [modernizr docs](http://modernizr.com/docs/) to confirm.

Comment: think I needed an extra library so I just did a check on Modernizr.input.placeholder and then included my file using ajax

Comment: That's pretty much what `Modernizr.load` is supposed to do. But if you've managed it another way, then that's also fine.

Comment: `Modernizr.load` isn't included in the dev version – you can create a custom build which includes it at http://modernizr.com/download. And please don't deploy a dev build to a production website :-)